# Using array.reduce to count occurances in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of voters:

```
let voters = [
    {name:'Bob' , age: 30, voted: true},
    {name:'Jake' , age: 32, voted: true},
    {name:'Kate' , age: 25, voted: false},
    {name:'Sam' , age: 20, voted: false},
    {name:'Phil' , age: 21, voted: true},
    {name:'Ed' , age:55, voted:true},
    {name:'Tami' , age: 54, voted:true},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 31, voted: false},
    {name: 'Becky', age: 43, voted: false},
    {name: 'Joey', age: 41, voted: true},
    {name: 'Jeff', age: 30, voted: true},
    {name: 'Zack', age: 19, voted: false}
];
```

That I need to count how many voted (`true`).

I was able to find it using a for loop, but I'm learning the `reduce` method, and would like to apply it here but can't seem to figure out how.

```
// works perfectly
function totalVotes(voters){
      let total = 0;
      for (i=0; i < voters.length; i++){
        if (voters[i].voted === true) {
          total++
        }
      }
      return total
    }
```

```
function totalVotes2(voters){
      voters.reduce(function (contador, item){
        if (item.voted === true){
          console.log(item)
          console.log(contador)
          //cant figure out how to make it count
          }
          // and how to return it
      }, 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the accumulator's initial value to `0` and add 1 to it if the current element's `voted` property is true and add `0` otherwise.

```js
let voters = [
    {name:'Bob' , age: 30, voted: true},
    {name:'Jake' , age: 32, voted: true},
    {name:'Kate' , age: 25, voted: false},
    {name:'Sam' , age: 20, voted: false},
    {name:'Phil' , age: 21, voted: true},
    {name:'Ed' , age:55, voted:true},
    {name:'Tami' , age: 54, voted:true},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 31, voted: false},
    {name: 'Becky', age: 43, voted: false},
    {name: 'Joey', age: 41, voted: true},
    {name: 'Jeff', age: 30, voted: true},
    {name: 'Zack', age: 19, voted: false}
];
let res = voters.reduce((acc, {voted})=>acc + (voted ? 1 : 0), 0);
console.log(res);
```

You could also make use of the fact that `true` can be coerced to `1` and `false` can be coerced to `0` in JavaScript, obviating the need for the ternary operator.

```js
let voters = [
    {name:'Bob' , age: 30, voted: true},
    {name:'Jake' , age: 32, voted: true},
    {name:'Kate' , age: 25, voted: false},
    {name:'Sam' , age: 20, voted: false},
    {name:'Phil' , age: 21, voted: true},
    {name:'Ed' , age:55, voted:true},
    {name:'Tami' , age: 54, voted:true},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 31, voted: false},
    {name: 'Becky', age: 43, voted: false},
    {name: 'Joey', age: 41, voted: true},
    {name: 'Jeff', age: 30, voted: true},
    {name: 'Zack', age: 19, voted: false}
];
let res = voters.reduce((acc, {voted})=>acc + voted, 0);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Dear @hev1, thanks! This works but now I don't understand how does {voted} captures the value of that KVP. Could you help me figure that out?

Comment: I just used {age}, with the accumulator set to zero, and it added up all ages, as expected. But I still don't understand how could {age} pick the value of age:number

Comment: It's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh! : ) Thanks!

Comment: @LeonardoNobreGhiggino No problem. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It leads me in the right direction, I believe. Now I need to study it better. Today I learned...